# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, chat

### Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2 ##

---

### build.gradle

---

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://maven.stickerpipe.com/artifactory/stickerfactory' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chat.application.chatapplicationdemo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.navercorp.pulltorefresh:library:3.2.3@aar'
    compile('vc908.stickers:stickerfactory:0.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-content-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-location-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc-2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Consider an update of your jdk

Comment: I update the **jdk version to jdk1.8.0_66** but i got same error @ Marged

Answer (score 0):

In your lib folder delete android_support_v4.jar and clean your project this works for me

Comment: thanks for answer but this solution is not worked for me :-( @muruga5000

Answer (score 0):

Don't include all play services. It includes many unnecessary classes

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

Instead add only neccecarry modules. For example

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'`